# Building maven from source

Tags: 12.04, install-from-source, maven-3

I'm trying to build maven from source (on Ubuntu 12.04) following the tutorial:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-building-m2.html

I installed a previous version of maven using

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

I then checked out maven using:

```
git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/maven.git maven
```

I then built maven using maven according to the apache guide, so I cd into the checkout version of maven and did:

```
sudo mvn install
```

this seemed to work fine, no errors or anything, but when I do

mvn -version

My output is:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.0-37-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Which is not the version I checked out, it's the version of maven I got from apt-get. What exactly did mvn install do? Where did it install maven to, and how do I update the mvn command?

I've been digging through the output of mvn-install . It seems it's creating jar files, for example, some of the outputs are:

```
[INFO] Installing /opt/maven/maven-core/target/maven-core-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-core-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /opt/maven/maven-core/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-core-3.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

if I cd into
    /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-core
and do a ls -la

I see

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 33 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:30 2.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:30 2.0.1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:30 2.0.6
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:30 2.0.9
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:31 2.2.1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:30 3.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 25 15:31 3.1-SNAPSHOT
```

The last entry seems really suspicious. If I change directory into that and list it's contents I see:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 557420 Sep 26 08:45 maven-core-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7270 Sep 26 08:44 maven-core-3.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    706 Sep 26 08:45 maven-metadata-local.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    186 Sep 26 08:45 _maven.repositories
```

Which is different then what the contents of

```
/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.0
```

are. They are:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6629 Sep 25 15:30 maven-core-3.0.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Sep 25 15:30 maven-core-3.0.pom.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  154 Sep 25 15:30 _maven.repositories
```

Answer (score 1):

Heh. 99% there, but stopped by the doorman. If you meant what you said, the problem is `mvn install` which doesn't install mvn. Man pages say maven has no "install" switch. It *should* have printed a "how's that?" error. Bad maven.

The canonical build-from-source routine goes like this, from the appropriate directory:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

*Make* install (d'oh!). Note the sudo, meaning, root privileges for you from now on, I'm sure you know.

I've never built maven myself, but after that last step I should expect to find the new program somewhere in /usr/local. /usr/local/share, in this case? With any luck, just `mvn` from the command line should find the new one after installing, and that's what you want of course. If not, you'll have to adjust your $PATH environment variable, and perhaps your library search configuration, but let's hope that's unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a ./configure nor a make file in the maven directory. It seems you build maven differently then other software. I did some digging and updated my question.